# I can't query in WebView context

Tags: css, webview, console, calabash, calabash-android

I'm facing a problem right now, and I need some help.

I have a native app that displays in some point a webView, the class for this webView is called: org.xwalk.core.XWalkView. I'm developing in Windows and running calabash-android console, but when I use any of this commands:

query("webView css:'*' ") or query("XWalkView css:'*' ")

I'm unavailable to get any object from that webview. Is this an abnormal behavior? What should I do to get the css values?

Thank you so much.

Cheers.

PS: calabash-android version 0.4.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade you Calabash-Android version to the latest one. 0.4.20 is a very old release and does not support crosswalk webviews.